# Unknown behaviour while typecasting a float to an int.

Tags: c, floating-point, typecast-operator

I wanted to typecast a float with the following code. change is a float and changeI is an int. The tricky input value is 0.41 since it can't be accurately represented in binary but I don't understand why this does not work.

```
changeI = (int)(change*100)
```

If I print just (change*100.0) it prints 41.0000003 or something equivalent, which to my understanding if I typecast i.e (int) it should just drop the floating point bits and leave the number as 41.

However, if I print the value of changeI I get 413 and I don't really know why.

Also, if I manually print (int)41.0000003 it is also printed as 413

Edit:

Ok, so I found the main problem, which is really stupid by the way (i was printing an extra 3 afterwards and forgot the new line character in the previous print but now it prints 40 instead of 41).
This is the full code.

```
int flag = 0;
float change;
int changeI;

do{
    printf("How much change is owed?: ");
    scanf("%f", &change);
    if (change >= 0){
         flag = 1;
    }
}while(!flag)

changeI = (int)(change*100.0);

printf("%f\n", change*100.0);
printf("%i\n", changeI);
printf("%i\n", (int)(41.0000003));
```

The output for 0.41 is:

```
>41.0000003
>40
>41
```

Edit2: As JackV stated, if you copy the float multiplied by 100 to another float and then typecast that new float it does print 41 but I would still like to know why does this happens.

Comment: Define `changeI` to be an `int`, not a `float`.

Comment: And how are you printing it??

Comment: printf("%d", changeI)

Comment: I doubt it.  It wouldn't print as 41.0000003 if you did.

Comment: Post more of the code.  There's no way anyone can help with what you've posted.

Comment: Sure, I'll post the rest of the code but it's not much

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Show us a simple code fragment that demonstrates the problem. You obviously aren't doing what you think you're doing, but without the code we can't say what. You _did_  recompile successfully and are running the new version, right?

Comment: Yeah, as I stated in the Edit section I was making a stupid mistake but I still don't understand why it prints 40 instead of 41

Comment: When you do it like this, it works for some reason: `change *= 100.0;
changeI = change;`

Comment: @FiddlingBits I guess that works by the same principle as JackV's solution but I would still like to know the reason.

Comment: Works if you make `change` a `double`, too.

Comment: It should not print 40. I did a printf("changeI = %d\n", changeI) for both changeI = change * 100; and changeI = (int)(change * 100); It printed 41 in both cases ... as it should.

Comment: Try doing it 100 times in a loop and it will print 40 sometimes and 41 the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly what you are doing but this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int changeI, newI;
    float change = 0.41, var = change * 100;
    changeI = (int)(change*100);
    newI = (int)(var);
    printf("%f", var); //prints 41.000000
    printf("int = %d\n", changeI); //prints 40
    printf("float = %f", change); //prints 0.410000
    printf("%d", newI); //prints 41
    return 0;
}
```

Works exactly as it should it prints:

int = 40

float = 0.410000

Comment: @Darwin57721 I didnt even notice that and im not sure why it does that but what i just edited my post with something new that worked. I simply multiplied the original float by 100 and stored it in a new float and then typecasted that value to an int

Comment: Thanks! That workaround worked! but I'd still like to know why is this the behaviour of the program.

Comment: Or should I post it as a new question?

Comment: @Darwin57721 Im fairly new to programming as well so I really cant tell you why it was doing that. If my answer satisfied you though please mark as accepted

Comment: Casting with `(int)` will always round down. Due to possible differences in rounding behaviour, it's almost random whether you will get 40 or 41 from a floating point number that should be 41. Best add 0.5 before casting to get round to nearest instead of round down behaviour.

Comment: @Rörd C doesn't round when casting a `float` to `int`, it truncates.

Comment: Thanks @Rörd that makes sense. I guess it's just the scope of the float type and then truncating a number close to 41 or 40. Adding 0.5 and then casting is the most elegant solution I can think of.

Comment: @FiddlingBits It doesn't really make a difference as long as were only talking about positive numbers, if I understand this correctly. But yes, generally speaking, "truncate" is a better description to describe C's behaviour than "round down".